# Add keybinding in Vim

Tags: vim, django

I am using vim pretty often with my work. I am a web developer in Django. I would like to build a keybinding so that each time it is executed it will print the line `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`. Could anyone have time to tell me how to do it?  If you could build the macro, I guess, it will be good too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `abbr`, in your `.vimrc`:

```
noreabbrev _i import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

now you can type `_i` <kbd>TAB</kbd> and it will complete it to `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`.

Comment: Prefer the non-recursive versions (`noreabbrev`), or you might end up 
 accidentally using the abbreviation in the expansion.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. Do you have another option?

Comment: For me it means I have to type `_ + i ` and press `TAB`. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah... it's right. it's just what I prefer you can use anything you like instead of `_i`.

Comment: Do you have another option?

Comment: It should work,  remember that you should be in "insert mode". you can see if `abbr _i import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` works.

Comment: Now I understand. It could be relevant to write what is in insert mode and what is in command mode. So `_i` has to be written in insert mode, and I after you have to type `TAB` in command mode. It is not obvious just with your answer.